# Arm-cortexA53 can support OpenCL?

Tags: android, opencl

About arm-cortexA53 ship info:https://www.arm.com/products/processors/cortex-a;

About opencl2.2 info:https://www.khronos.org/opencl/

```
 I have huawei nova young  really phone, cpu is Arm-cortexA53.Now i want to  do some OPENCL practices on this smart phone,but i don't know how to start. my compile platform is Android studio 2.3.3.
```

thank U

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be very difficult using OpenCL on Android platforms.

Best bet would be to use Renderscript or use Neon library [Ne10](https://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/)

I you are after OpenCL then you would have to look for opensource projects like PoCL.